# DevExpress Gridview can't show data

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, datasource

I have this code :

```
private void frmWeld_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Weld> lst = _weldRepository.Get().ToList();
    gridControl.DataSource = new BindingList<Weld>(lst) { AllowNew = true };
}
```

I want to load my data into `devExpressGridView`

[image]

As you can see my data is loaded but the gridview can't show the data and my break point doesn't pass from `gridControl.DataSource = new BindingList<Weld>(lst) { AllowNew = true}` and my program remains with this state.
Why?

I just add new column to my gridview after this the problems occurreded.
I use entity framework ,when i change the database my application creates a new database using code first and after that my data is lost but the problem that i said is solved.

Comment: if you just assign lst directly to the data source, what would happen?

Comment: @woodykiddy same error

Comment: What is the error if you debug?

Comment: I said no error happens just the gridview doesn't show ant data ,something like  stopped

Comment: Do you see rows with blank cells, or no rows at all?

Comment: Did you contact the [DevExpress support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)? Did you provide the minimal reproducible example? What did their support guys say?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is executing in `Load` event, add `ForceInitialize()` to your code.

```
private void frmWeld_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  // your previous code
  gridControl.ForceInitialize(); <- add this line
}
```